# Metaprogramming in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I would like to generate some combinatorial logic, and I would like to use recursive functions for this (with predefined preprocessor arguments, of course).

Simple example: **Factorial function**

I have a **reg [10:0] number;** and I want to have the logic for counting it's factorial, but I want some predefined variable **msb** to be determine the MSB and have **number[msb:0]** as a starting number, and go on from there.

And module would receive the number and call fact_func(number) which would calcuate the factorial, but only the shortened one.

Is something like this possible in Verilog? Have functions generate logic?

Comment: "where instead of" what? And what is "the shortened one"?

Comment: "where insead of" is something I forgot to remove. "the shortened one" is to use predefined msb instead of 10 (not always 'shortened')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but building logic with recursive function calls is very much possible in Verilog. You'll need to build a parameterized module that includes a generate block instantiating itself with a progressively smaller (or larger) parameter value, until you get to the base case.

[Here's](https://www.beyond-circuits.com/wordpress/2009/01/recursive-modules/) an example of it in action. You could easily modify this to generate the Fibonacci sequence.

Keep in mind, however, that generating blocks this way can synthesize very, very large. You will need to ensure the tools you're using are succeeding in optimizing it to a reasonable size.

Comment: Although It seemed recursive modules are a solution, I couldn't use my genvars in expressions, e.g. genvar i,j; i = j + 3; only in **for** loops. Correct me if I am wrong. I will look into hypertext preprocessors then.